# Проверка "реальности" e-mail на PHP

Tags: php

Пожалуйста подскажите. Вопрос следующий: в интернет - магазине (форма заказа) не хочется подключать CAPTCHA из-за "особенностей" клиентов (они начинают "ругаться", когда необходимо вводить буквы, цифры и пр. :) И, как следствие, уходят с сайта). В форме стандартное поле ввода e-mail. Как проверить, реальный e-mail или "от барабана". На отдельных сайтах можно писать все что угодно, лишь бы символ @ был.

Comment: Как насчёт отправить письмо с подтверждением или даже с ссылкой, как для активации, только активировать заказ?

Comment: Само собой уже после проверки на валидность.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. +1

Answer (score 4):

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // валидный
}
else {
    // не валидный
}
```

[Validate filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)

Ответ на "как узнать, есть ли такой ящик": [специальный класс и примеры](http://code.google.com/p/php-smtp-email-validation/source/browse/#svn/trunk)

Надо только учесть, что можно любой чужой ящик ввести при этом.

Comment: я полагаю e-mail надо проверить не на валидность, а на существование.

Comment: Спасибо. Прийду к домашнему компу, попробую. Но еще вопрос (только не смейтесь), почту от web-сервисов (...mail.ru, ukr.net) будет проверять?

Comment: FLK, я неправильно выразился. Действительно, проверять на существование.

Comment: По словам "На отдельных сайтах можно писать все что угодно, лишь бы символ @ был." я понял так, что надо именно на валидность проверить. А так надо через ссылку проверять. Высылать сгенерированный ключ, требуя прохождения по ссылке. Иначе все будут вводить "info@microsoft.com" и всё :)

Comment: А не лучше проверять через JS. А по поводу перехода по ссылкам, если капчю лень ввести, то тогда я думаю и по ссылке перейти будет трудновато

Comment: Вопрос в следующем: есть или нет такого почтового адреса. Не спрашивайте зачем. Так надо.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. +1

Comment: @Вячеслав Кириченко, тогда я неправильно понял сначала. Добавил.

Comment: @kremchik вспомнил, почему не пользуюсь встроенными фильтрами, они не подддерживают кирилические домены например: инфо@почта.рф распознается как невалидный.

Comment: @Вячеслав Кириченко, класс по ссылке не определяет?

Comment: Функция `filter_var()` криво проверяет валидность адресов.